# SWD Signals multiplexing

Tags: stm32, swd

I design a pcb with STM's STM32F4 microcontroller and i'm going to use the SWD interface for programming.
My Question is: Could those pins to shared (*after programming*) with other signals on pcb? Signals such as led on/off trace, chip's reset trace, etc.

Comment: How are you planning to multiplex them? The SWD interface is designed to ignore anything except a specific connection sequence, so there is a chance this will be possible. More detail will help people to identify problems with your plan.

Comment: I want to use them for other functionality after programming, as I mentioned above

Comment: You'll need to be more specific - I don't have a datasheet to hand to know if there is internal multiplexing.

Comment: Yes there is. After programming my mC, i want to use them as GPIO. The question is if I can do that.

Comment: Does SWD work, if those signals are used as GPIO?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to remap the jtag/swd pins. If you are using the stm half it's:

```
GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_Disable, ENABLE);
```

If not you need to look for the correct registers in the datasheet.

Be careful to implement a fallback scenario to reenable the swd/jtag pins or to use another update mechanism. This to be able to update the software afterwards.

The swd/jtag port is not usable after the remap.